# How do I make navigator.geolocation timeout timer start AFTER the user has authorised it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

As you know, HTML Geolocation has to be authorised by the user via the browser. I'm running a timeout of 5 seconds and noticed that if the user takes longer to click Accept (or Deny), then it will simply stop working. Is there a way to make the timer start after the user has clicked Accept/Deny rather than when the function is called?

Here's how I call it:

```
navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition(
         showPosition, showError, showProgress, 
         {desiredAccuracy:1500, maxWait:5000}
);
```

And the function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition = function (showPosition, showError, showProgress, options) {
    var lastCheckedPosition,
        locationEventCount = 0,
        watchID,
        timerID;

    options = options || {};

    var checkLocation = function (position) {
        lastCheckedPosition = position;
        locationEventCount = locationEventCount + 1;
        // We ignore the first event unless it's the only one received because some devices seem to send a cached
        // location even when maxaimumAge is set to zero
        if ((position.coords.accuracy <= options.desiredAccuracy) && (locationEventCount > 1)) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            foundPosition(position);
        } else {
            showProgress(position);
        }
    };

    var stopTrying = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        foundPosition(lastCheckedPosition);
    };

    var onError = function (error) {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        showError(error);
    };

    var foundPosition = function (position) {
        showPosition(position);
    };

    if (!options.maxWait)            options.maxWait = 5000; // Default 5 seconds
    if (!options.desiredAccuracy)    options.desiredAccuracy = 1500; // Default 1500 meters
    if (!options.timeout)            options.timeout = options.maxWait; // Default to maxWait

    options.maximumAge = 0; // Force current locations only
    options.enableHighAccuracy = true; // Force high accuracy (otherwise, why are you using this function?)

    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(checkLocation, onError, options);
    timerID = setTimeout(stopTrying, options.maxWait); // Set a timeout that will abandon the location loop
};
```

Comment: Your code, on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7gf8pL74/